# PHP program cannot connect to Postgresql DB

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

My PHP program is trying to connection to PostgreSQL DB located on another machine but when the web page loads it just says "`Could not find driver`".

I google around and found that I had to uncomment `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
and `extension=php_pgsql.dll` in `php.ini` which I already did. Not sure what else I could be missing. Please guide.

**database.php**

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private static $dbName = 'istore-db' ;
    private static $dbHost = 'gsi-547576.gsiccorp.net' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'postgres';
    private static $dbUserPassword = 'postgres';
    private static $dbPort = '5432';

    private static $cont  = null;

    public function __construct() {
        die('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static function connect()
    {
       // One connection through whole application
       if ( null == self::$cont )
       {     
        try
        {
          //self::$cont =  new PDO( "pgsql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
          self::$cont = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=" . self::$dbName . ";host=" .self::$dbHost . ";port=" .self::$dbPort, self::$dbUsername,  self::$dbUserPassword);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          die($e->getMessage()); 
        }
       }
       return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect()
    {
        self::$cont = null;
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Active</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        include 'database.php';
                        $pdo = Database::connect();
                        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY  NAME';
                        foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['category_id'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td>' . $row['active'] . '</td>';
                            echo '<td width=250>';
                            echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Read</a>';
                            echo ' ';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Update</a>';
                            echo ' ';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                        }
                        Database::disconnect();
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to restart your webserver ?

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the operating system? DLL files are only useful for Windows installations.

Comment: Yes I restarted my webserver and the OS is Windows 7. Do we have to add any other driver file(s) during deployment. I am asking this because I didnt add any. I just copied over the .php files from my DEV machine to htdocs folder in Apache web server.

Comment: You got some advance?

Comment: @Adrian: I kind of left this pet project as I did not make any progress on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
self::$cont =  new PDO( "pgsql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword);
```

to

```
self::$cont = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=" . self::$dbName . ";host=" .self::$dbHost, self::$dbUsername,  self::$dbUserPassword);
```

Comment: Tried the new string that you provided Adrian after restarting the Web server but still no luck :(

Comment: The funny thing is that I have a java program and PostgreSQL Manager tool and they are both able to connect to remote PostgreSQL server using the same credentials, hostname and DB name.

Comment: @user2325154 if you can connect with yours credential, forget change the line to localhost, change only self:;$cont ... see my edit

Comment: I don't see any difference between the new line and the older line that you posted earlier. However I have copy-pasted your suggestion and still no luck.

Comment: Put in $dbHost the name with you connect with your PostgreSQL Manager tool

Comment: I replaced localhost with machine name gsi-547576.net and also added the port 5432 something in the connect string but still no luck. database.php modified above to reflect my new changes.